# Python function returns uncode strings instead of datetime objects

Tags: python, datetime

I have a work around for this problem, but I want to know why it is a problem.
In the code below the filter function is a list of unicode strings rather than the datetime objects that is_date_string makes

```
import re
import requests

datestrings = re.compile(r'\d*-\d*-\d* \d*:\d*:\d*')

def is_date_string(s):
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    except:
        return False

d = filter(is_date_string,datestrings.findall(request.text))
```

this is a sample of the data that the regex produces:

```
 DATESTRINGS = 
    [u'2016-06-24 05:36:42', u'2016-06-24 04:53:02', u'2016-06-24 04:53:02', u'2016-06-24 04:53:02', u'2016-06-24 04:53:02', u'2016-06-24 04:53:02', u'2016-06-24 04:53:02', u'2016-06-24 04:53:03', u'2016-06-24 04:53:04', u'2016-06-24 04:53:04', u'2016-06-24 04:53:04', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:05', u'2016-06-24 04:53:', u'2016-06-24 05:18:56', u'2016-06-24 05:36:43', u'2016-06-27 05:00:00']
```

my work around is a list comprehension on d to do what the function should do

```
dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for x in d if x]
```

However the question is about the is_date_string function not returning datetime objects. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter use the result of the function to do filtering but the return is the subset of the iterable, which is in your case a string.

What you want seems something like this

`d = filter(None, map(is_date_string,datestrings.findall(request.text)))`

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter
From the doc

> Note that filter(function, iterable) is equivalent to `[item for item in iterable if function(item)]` if function is not `None` and `[item for item in iterable if item]` if function is `None`.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood how filter works. All I needed was a list comprehension. This works `[x for x in map(is_date_string,datestrings.findall(request.text)) if x]`